# Having trouble to find segmentation fault

Tags: c

Im working on my school project and lately I have been struggling to find segmentation fault error in my code. Could you please check the code for me? The input is "Hello world!" and the function should convert each characters into bits. The a variable at the end is just for checking whether I can print it or not (I cannot). Thanks

```
unsigned char* bit_encrypt(const char* text){
  char text_copy[strlen(text)];
  printf("Strlen: %ld\n", strlen(text));
  bool bits[strlen(text_copy)][8];
  int dec = 0;
  int j = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++){
    text_copy[i] = text[i];
    dec = (int)text_copy[i];

      if(dec >= 128){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 128;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec >= 64){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 64;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec >= 32){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 32;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec >= 16){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 16;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec >= 8){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 8;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec >= 4){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 4;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec >= 2){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 2;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      j++;

      if(dec == 1){
        bits[i][j] = true;
        dec = dec - 1;
      }
      else{
        bits[i][j] = false;
      }
      dec = 0;
      j = 0;
  }
  text_copy[strlen(text)] = '\0';

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text_copy); i++){
    printf("%c:  ", text_copy[i]); 
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
      printf("%d ", bits[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  int a = 53;
  printf("%d", a);




 /* unsigned char* vystup = (unsigned char*)calloc(strlen(text_copy), sizeof(unsigned char*));
*/

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
Strlen: 12
H:  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
e:  0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
l:  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
l:  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
o:  0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
 :  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
w:  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
o:  0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
r:  0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
l:  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
d:  0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
!:  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `bool bits[strlen(text_copy)][8];` but text_copy is empty. Try strlen(text) here?

Comment: `text_copy[strlen(text)] = '\0';` will write out of bounds!

Comment: @Rup Not "empty", but *indeterminate*, and leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Fair enough, I meant 'hasn't been initialised'

Comment: ack, my eyes!  `bits[i][j] = !!(dec & (1<<7-j))`

Comment: A [mcve] might help here too.

Comment: Learning how to use a debugger will help you a lot in situations like this one.

Comment: A print statement to check whether some code is reached or not isn't a bad idea, but you should end such statements with a newline `\n` or print to `stderr` to flush the output buffer. Otherwise the print may execute, but you may not see the output yet.

Comment: I was thinking valgrind because sometimes an "invalid write" is not nearby the line of code where a motivated "invalid read" happens. In a debugger, "why does this variable have this value, I just set it in a function called three lines ago?" is a question that is not always easy to answer.

Comment: Depends on whether he is using Windows or Linux.  AFIK valgrind only works on Linux.

Comment: @cup I works really well on linux. it works ok on slightly older versions of macOS. It's a kludge on Windows. I use a linux virtual machine on my macOS host, share my home folder with the vm, and then have gradle compile for the guest. Works like a charm.

Comment: Since I could't solve my problem while using 2D array, I managed to make it work with one-dimensional array (seg fault simply disappeared). So I want to thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, what you are doing, i.e. scrambling

Simply validating your input and initializing variables will eliminate *most* (not all) of your problems:

```
unsigned char* bit_encrypt(const char* text)
{
    int len = 0;
    //validate input:
    if(!text) return NULL;
    if((len = strlen(text)) == 0) return NULL;//capture length using strlen once, leave if 0
    char text_copy[len+1]; //+1 for termination char , uninitialized
    memset(text_copy, 0, sizeof(text_copy));//initialized  
    printf("Strlen: %ld\n", len);
    bool bits[len][8]; //uninitialized
    memset(bits, 0, sizeof(bits));//initialized
    int dec = 0;
    int j = 0;
```

Then, at bottom, the following change is optional, but to avoid calling `strlen in a loop get the length once, then use it in the loop:

Modification of code after the loop:

```
....
}
text_copy[len] = '\0';
len = strlen(text_copy);//again, get length once to avoid calling it in loop
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    printf("%c:  ", text_copy[i]); 
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        printf("%d ", bits[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int a = 53;
printf("%d", a);
```

These changes resulted in the same output but without the exception:

[image]

***EDIT*** to address question in comments:
The following code creates a `bool **scramble`, `strlen("Hello World!")` rows and `8` columns, but it is done dynamically, then freed when done.
This is to address your question in the comments:
_but still got the Segmentation fault. Printf("%d", a) was ignored. Could it be because of returning 0; and having main: unsigned char* encrypted; encrypted = bit_encrypt("Hello world!"); printf("%s\n", encrypted); ??_.
You did not include `main()` in your original post, so I cannot answer why you got the *seg-fault*.  However, I have included `int main(void){...}` so I could illustrate one way of returning the data without *seg-fault*. Here is my complete code:

```
    bool  **bit_encrypt(const char* text);
    bool ** Create2D(int c, int r);
    void free2D(bool **arr, int c);

    int main(void)
    {
        bool **scambled = bit_encrypt("Hello World!");
        //scrabled is not a 2D arranged set of bits, 8 wide with strlen("Hello World!") long
        free2D(scambled, strlen("Hello World!"));
        return 0;
    }
    bool **bit_encrypt(const char* text)
    {
        int len = 0;
        //validate input:
        if(!text) return NULL;
        if((len = strlen(text)) == 0) return NULL;//capture length using strlen once, leave if 0
        char text_copy[len+1]; //+1 - room for null
        memset(text_copy, 0, len+1);//initialized  
        printf("Strlen: %ld\n", len);
        bool **bits = Create2D(len, 8); //uninitialized, changed from bool to match return of prototype
        if(!bits) return NULL;
        int dec = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            text_copy[i] = text[i];
            dec = (int)text_copy[i];

            if(dec >= 128){
                    bits[i][j] = true;
                    dec = dec - 128;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec >= 64){
                bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 64;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec >= 32){
                bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 32;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec >= 16){
                bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 16;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec >= 8){
            bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 8;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec >= 4){
                bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 4;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec >= 2){
                bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 2;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            j++;

            if(dec == 1){
                bits[i][j] = true;
                dec = dec - 1;
            }
            else{
                bits[i][j] = false;
            }
            dec = 0;
            j = 0;
        }
        text_copy[len] = '\0';
        len = strlen(text_copy);//again, get length once to avoid calling it in loop
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            printf("%c:  ", text_copy[i]); 
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                printf("%d ", bits[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        int a = 53;
        printf("%d", a);

        return bits;
    }

    bool ** Create2D(int c, int r)
    {   
        bool **arr;
        int    y;

        arr   = calloc(c, sizeof(bool *));
        for(y=0;y<c;y++)
        {
            arr[y] = calloc(r, sizeof(bool));  
        }
        return arr;
    }

    void free2D(bool **arr, int c)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            free(arr[i]);
        }
        free(arr);
    }
```

Comment: I follow all of this but still got the Segmentation fault. Printf("%d", a) was ignored. Could it be because of returning 0; and having main:

 unsigned char* encrypted;
 encrypted = bit_encrypt("Hello world!"); 
 printf("%s\n", encrypted);

???

Comment: @MartinCigarsky -  I will edit to include the exact code that produced my results.  I may have left something out of what I included in in this answer.  See edits in awhile... (I have something pressing to attend to at this time.)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array `char text_copy[strlen(text)]` you don't initialize values in it. At this point, it is populated with garbage.
Then you try to get the length of the string out of it. `bool bits[strlen(text_copy)][8]`. `strlen` is counting number of characters till it finds '/0'. Because of that, you get a wrong length of string and get the array `bits[]` of wrong size. 
When you start populating `bits[]` with values you're using the length of `text`, not `text_copy`. C compiler allows you to overwrite values beyond of `bits[]` and some data in other variables becomes damaged. 
At some point of programm you are trying to access data that is stored beyond the size of `bits[]` and that might cause the segmentation fault.

If you change `bool bits[strlen(text_copy)][8];` to `bool bits[strlen(text)][8];` the programm will execute as supposed.

Comment: Still a segmentation fault. Variable a never got printed. Could it be because of my main?

  unsigned char* encrypted;
  encrypted = bit_encrypt("Hello world!"); 
  printf("%s\n", encrypted);

Comment: Well, look... `unsigned char* encrypted` declares a pointer `encrypted` to a value of `char` type. It's an address to memory, not actual value. Address not defined, value itself not defined. As you may remember `bit_encrypt()` returns `int`.  In this statement `encrypted = bit_encrypt("Hello world!")` you assign `int` to pointer without type casting. This is not critical, but not a good practice. In result, as `bit_encrypt()` returns `0` you get NULL pointer. A pointer to nowhere. At the end `printf("%s\n", encrypted)`  expects argument of type `string` (`%s\n`) and you give it a pointer.

Comment: Actually `unsigned char* encrypted; encrypted = bit_encrypt("Hello world!"); printf("%s\n", encrypted);` I don't get segmentation fault... But if I try to get value out of pointer `printf("%s\n", *encrypted)` then I get segmentation fault at this statement. Because `encrypted == NULL` points to nowhere.

Comment: As we don't see your entire code we can't replicate your experience...